# My PHP variable is not receiving data from my AJAX (WordPress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am having problems with my PHP variable not receiving the data I passed using AJAX.

Here is my script:

```
   jQuery('.ch-user > div .ch-function button').click(function(){ 
        var userID = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-id'); // User ID
        var userName = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-name'); // User display name
        var userProgress = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-progress'); // Challenge progress in percentage
        var userCHL = jQuery(this).attr('data-user-chl'); // No. of challenges completed

        jQuery('.popup-details').attr('data-id', userID);
        jQuery('.popup-details .pd-name').text(userName);
        jQuery('.popup-details .pd-progress .ch-progress-number').text(userCHL + ' / 30');
        jQuery('.popup-details .pd-progress .ch-progress').attr('style', 'max-width:' + userProgress + '%;');
        jQuery('.popup-details').addClass('open');
        console.log(userID);
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: 'chu_plugin_settings_page', user_id : userID, user_name : userName},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Challenge Complete!');  
                jQuery('#ch-users-display').html(response.user_id);
            }
        })

    });
```

And here is where the data values should be used:

```
                    $userCHID = $_POST['user_id'];
                    $userCHNAME = $_POST['user_name'];
                    $chUserMETA = get_user_meta($userCHID, 'challenge', true);
                    $chCOMP = (empty($chUserMETA)) ? 0 : count($chUserMETA);
                    $chPUB = wp_count_posts( 'challenge' )->publish;
                    $chLEFT = ($chCOMP == 0) ? $chPUB - 0 : $chPUB - $chCOMP;
                    if (!empty($userCHID)) :
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'challenge',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => $chLeft, 
                            'meta_key' => 'day',
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                            'order' => 'ASC', 
                        ); $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                                $badgeIcon = ''; 
                                $dayfield = get_field('day');
                                $day = (!empty(get_field('day'))) ? 'Day '.$dayfield : '';
                                $challengeName = get_the_title();
                                echo (!empty($dayfield)) ? '
                                <div class="pd-challenge">
                                    <div class="ch-day">'.$day.'</div>
                                    <div class="ch-name">'.$challengeName.'</div>
                                    <div class="ch-date">Date Completed: MM/DD/YYYY</div>
                                </div>
                                ' : '';
                            endwhile; wp_reset_query(); 
                        else :
                            echo 'No challenges yet';
                        endif;
                    else :
                        echo '<div>Cannot find user ID...</div>';
                        echo $chPUB.' - '.$chCOMP.' = '.$chLEFT.' [user_id : '.$userCHID.', ch_user_meta : '.$chUserMETA[0].', user_name ; '.$userCHNAME.']';
                    endif;
```

I needed the **user_id** to get the details and output the data in the user's user-meta.

So the script works perfectly fine, so it confuses me why it doesn't work on the PHP side as the **$_POST['user_id']** and **$_POST['user_name']** are empty.

Comment: Please share more details. Does that script run perfectly fine, or are you facing any problem?

Comment: Try using the `data()` method instead, eg. `var userID = jQuery(this).data('user-id')` and so on. `attr()` will read from the DOM, but if you changed the value during runtime it may not have been updated in the DOM. Also, check the network tab of the console to ensure the request is actually reaching the server, and there's not an error response code.

Comment: Hello Nico, I am not encountering any problems with the script, and yes when checking the network responce, it all goes through.

Comment: _"And here is where the data values should be used:"_ - what's the context of that code, where did you bind this to your AJAX action?

Comment: If you are not facing any problems, what's your question? If everything is already working, what do you need help with?